# Windows Image on Docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-image

How can I create an image in Docker with Windows as the base OS.

For instance; the '**FROM**' command in a Dockerfile is used to load the base OS kernel. Eg: '**FROM ubuntu**'(ubuntu kernel in this case).

Is there a way in which I can run a command like '**FROM windows7**'.
I need it to setup image for build purpose, since I need to run Microsoft compiler 'cl' ; which runs only on windows.

So the dockerfile will look something like:

FROM windows7

RUN install cl

...

Answer (score 0):

Not yet!
Docker depends on the sharing of an linux kernel.

In the moment Microsoft and Docker are working on a Windows version, sharing the windows kernel. This is already working! But only for windows 10 insider build. Where a special linux kernel like micro windows is included, which is then the base for the windows container.

A

> FROM windows7

will never exist. Depending on the architecture of windows7.

Comment: Thanks for quick response